# Conditionally replace values in pandas.DataFrame with previous value

Tags: python, pandas

I need to filter outliers in a dataset. Replacing the outlier with the previous value in the column makes the most sense in my application.

I was having considerable difficulty doing this with the `pandas` tools available (mostly to do with copies on slices, or type conversions occurring when setting to `NaN`).

Is there a fast and/or memory efficient way to do this? (Please see my answer below for the solution I am currently using, which also has limitations.)

---

A simple example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,1000,6,7,8],'B':list('abcdefgh')})
>>> df
      A  B
0     1  a
1     2  b
2     3  c
3     4  d
4  1000  e # '1000  e' --> '4  e'
5     6  f
6     7  g
7     8  h
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply mask values over your threshold and use `ffill`:

```
df.assign(A=df.A.mask(df.A.gt(10)).ffill())
```

```
     A  B
0  1.0  a
1  2.0  b
2  3.0  c
3  4.0  d
4  4.0  e
5  6.0  f
6  7.0  g
7  8.0  h
```

Using `mask` is necessary rather than something like `shift`, because it guarantees non-outlier output in the case that the previous value is also above a threshold.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. However, this has the issue with implicit type conversion during the `NaN` insertion which I alluded to. Is it possible to avoid this?

Comment: You can avoid by casting back to int, or using a `numpy` masked array potentially

Comment: Can you update with an example of the `np` masked array? I'd prefer not to always cast back to `int`, since the column may be `float` in other instances.

Comment: @nivk `df.assign(A=pd.to_numeric(df.A.mask(df.A.gt(10)).ffill(), downcast='integer'))` should flexibly convert the types. You might even go from float to int if all of the floats are outliers and get replaced.

Comment: @ALollz Thank you, this seems to do the trick. I am not sure I understand why the type conversion happens in the first place, which is always unnerving, but this should do for now.

Comment: It happens because `NaN` is a float

Answer (score 0):

I circumvented some of the issues with `pandas` copies and slices by converting to a `numpy` array first, doing the operations there, and then re-inserting the column. I'm not certain, but as far as I can tell, the datatype is the same once it is put back into the `pandas.DataFrame`.

```
def df_replace_with_previous(df,col,maskfunc,inplace=False):
    arr = np.array(df[col])
    mask = maskfunc(arr)
    arr[ mask ] = arr[ list(mask)[1:]+[False] ]
    if inplace:
        df[col] = arr
        return
    else:
        df2 = df.copy()
        df2[col] = arr
        return df2
```

This creates a mask, shifts it down by one so that the `True` values point at the previous entry, and updates the array. Of course, this will need to run recursively if there are multiple adjacent outliers (N times if there are N consecutive outliers), which is not ideal.

Usage in the case given in OP:

```
df_replace_with_previous(df,'A',lambda x:x>10,False)
```